# Multiple if conditions not working in function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function in which we compare the value. I am using two `if` `else` conditions and for some reason it is not going to the second `if` statement. Val Would be Either Male or Female in this condition. We are checking for male or female values in this. We get the gender_val as male or female but its not going to the next if statement.

```
var select_male = '';
var select_female = '';
var gender_val ='';
if ($.isNumeric(val)){
    gender_val='';
   }
else{
    gender_val = val.toLowerCase(); 
  }
if (gender_val == 'male' || gender_val == 'm'){
    select_male = 'active';
 }
else if (gender_val == 'female' || gender_val == 'f'){
    select_female = 'active';
 }
```

this is my code.. Its not going into the `if (gender_val == 'male' || gender_val == 'm')` statement. Can someone help me with this.

Comment: Please use `{` `}` code like this is terrible to read, maintain and extremely error prone during updates.

Comment: Can you also tell us what `val` holds?

Comment: Have you tried putting a debugger in the code and stepping thru?

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Comment: First guess would be that `if ($.isNumeric(val))` is true. What do you see in the console when doing `console.log(val)`?

Comment: I would like to recommend you to use `===` instead of `==`

Comment: @Sourav, please check the following **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tnaktt0k/)**. Your code, in my understanding, is working fine(*second if is being called*). Please check and update if anything there is a query.

Comment: Val is the value for the gender it would be male or female. I get the gender_val as male. But its not going to the next condition. I don't know why. It's not throwing any errors too .

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show what `val` is _by code_. The description doesn’t help.

Answer (score 1):

Lets consider you code line by line, considering `val = "19"`:

```
var select_male = '';
var select_female = '';
var gender_val ='';
```

and here nothing is wrong for me. But probably I would use some sort of boolean value instead of empty strings.

```
if ($.isNumeric(val)) // what is val? if it is a number then of course you will never enter later statements. But for our "19" this is a solid true.
  gender_val='';
else
  gender_val = val.toLowerCase(); 
// lets add here a logging for val you will tell us what you are really receiving in val
console.log(val);
```

Let's go to the conditions. At this point `gender_val` is `''`.

```
//      false            ||       false      is false
if (gender_val == 'male' || gender_val == 'm')
  select_male = 'active'; // we are not entering here
//      false            ||       false      is false    
else if (gender_val == 'female' || gender_val == 'f')
  select_female = 'active'; // we are not entering here neither
```

so we ended your snippets. The final result is:

```
select_male is ''
select_female is ''
gender_val is ''
```

If `val` is in some way: `male`, `Male`, `m`, `M` etc... etc...the final result would be:

```
select_male is 'active'
select_female is ''
gender_val is val in lowercase
```

specular for `female`, `F` etc...

Let's test it:

```js
function test(val) {
  // This is your code, only copied and pasted...
  var select_male = '';
  var select_female = '';
  var gender_val ='';
  if ($.isNumeric(val)) {
    gender_val='';
  }
  else{
    gender_val = val.toLowerCase(); 
  }
  if (gender_val == 'male' || gender_val == 'm') {
    select_male = 'active';
  }
  else if (gender_val == 'female' || gender_val == 'f') {
   select_female = 'active';
  }
  
  console.log([select_male, select_female, gender_val]);
}

// Some test call
test("19");      // Does not work due to $.isNumeric...
test("MaLe");    // Works!
test("f");       // Works!
test("what?");   // Nothing in the gender, is not passing the ifs.
test(undefined); // ooops! Error here!
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Please notice the error in case of an `undefined` input, generated by `toLowerCase`.